# Unable to take input in correct format in c#

Tags: c#, input, console

A rookie into it, I am unable to take input from Console properly using the following code.

```
int id;
string name;
float duration;
float price;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie id");
id = Convert.ToInt16(Console.Read());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie name");
name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie duration");
duration = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie price");
price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

bl.addMovie(id, name, duration, price);
```

Comment: What is the problem or error?

Comment: you are using ToInt16 conversion on id is there any special reason for this.

Comment: It is strange that you are using Convert.ToInt32 on something that you are assigning to a float, both for duration and price.

Comment: Actually the problem is with the "name = Console.ReadLine();" line, the lines asking to enter movie name and duration are printed without waiting for the name input.

Comment: Not really, Nishant. You're misunderstanding what's happening there. See Jim's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [Console.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `int` that represents the next character input. So what happens is that you enter multiple characters and hit Enter and the `Read` returns a single character. Then the `ReadLine` returns the rest of the characters as the string.

Replace your calls to `Read` with calls to `ReadLine`.

Answer (score 2):

Read only accepts the next character.

Try:

```
float price;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie price");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int successStatus = float.TryParse(input, out price);
bool success = successStatus != 0;
```

Or simply:

```
float price;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie price");
price = (float) Convert.ToDouble(Console.Readline())
```

The first is preferred because it is better at handling errors when parsing. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t.aspx). `float.TryParse` is synonymous with `Single.TryParse`

Comment: "it is better at handling errors when parsing" - but sample show no error handling - so in current form first is actually worse as it hides invalid inputs.

Comment: TryParse has internal handling.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is validate each input to be what you want, this is one way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int id;
    string name;
    float duration;
    float price;

    do
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie id");
    }
    while(!int.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(), out id));

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie name");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie duration");
    }
    while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out duration));

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie price");
    }
    while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out price));

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", id, name, duration, price);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked fine.Use the Console.ReadLine.

  int id;
            string name;
            float duration;
            float price;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie id");
            id = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie duration");
            duration = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie price");
            price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```